# How to exclude a module from test coverage calculations for a Ballerina package?

Tags: ballerina, ballerina-swan-lake

I have a Ballerina package with multiple modules, and one of them consists mostly of autogenerated code for which I currently do not have tests.

When I generate test coverage report, the overall coverage percentage is heavily impacted by the absence of tests for that particular module. Is there a method or configuration to exclude this module from the overall test coverage calculations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply exclude generated sources from coverage as follows,

```
bal test --test-report --code-coverage --coverage-format=xml --excludes='./generated'
```

If you want to exclude a single Ballerina source file from coverage you can pass the file path with `excludes` flag. You can also use glob patterns to exclude different set of source files.

For more info refer https://ballerina.io/learn/test-ballerina-code/execute-tests/#generate-test-report-and-code-coverage